# How to configure Tomcat 7 for SQL Server 2008 for use in java servlet programs?

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, configure

I searched whole internet and on this site but I was unable to get the answer. I am developing an servlet and jsp application. In which I created a form in jsp which will redirect its entered data to a servlet and that servlet will transfer that data to a database class that will insert it in a database. My project managers want me to use SQL Server 2008. I installed tomcat 7 and SQL Server 2008. I set the CLASSPATH to the path of sqljdbc.jar. I had done all the settings as found on a tutorial on net. But I am getting an exception as mentioned below.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. Please anyone tell me clean and step by step procedure to configure tomcat 7 for sql server 2008 database connectivity. Please its really urgent because I have to submit my project before 5 of next month. Thank you in advance.........

Exception I'm getting......

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
>  Stack Trace:
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
> ```
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>   at 
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method) at 
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown
>   Source) at 
>   DatabaseClass.openConnection(DatabaseClass.java:22)
>   at 
>   DatabaseClass.(DatabaseClass.java:49)
>   at 
>   BankMasterAddServlet.doPost(BankMasterAddServlet.java:10)
>   at 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>   at 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at 
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
>   at 
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:286)
>   at 
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:272)
>   at 
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1730)
>   at 
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source) at 
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source) at 
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 8):

> I set the CLASSPATH to the path of sqljdbc.jar

I do not believe that Tomcat uses any `CLASSPATH` environment properties that you have defined.

You can either deploy the jar file in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp or add it to the server's `lib` directory to have the classes available to all applications.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on the MSDN site. I was loading the SQL Server driver using the old notation as `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` but in newer versions like in SQL Server 2008 they changed the driver name to `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` and now it's working.